# How can I get all <li> elements where <span class="x"> using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How can I get all list elements having a `<span>` element with `class="required"`

```
<form id="aform">
  <ul>
    <li id="name" >
      <label class="description" for="name">Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
      <div>
        <input id="brand_name" name="brand_name" class="text textfield50pc" type="text" maxlength="40" value="<?php echo $brand->name; ?>"/> 
      </div> 
    </li>
  </ul>    
</form>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try: `$('li').has('span.required')`

Comment: Ah, I knew there was something like that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
var listElements = $('li').has('span.required');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jdHFD/1/).

Comment: That's a misleading variable name. (a) You don't call it `$listElement` to signify a jQuery object [ok, personal choice]; (b) You call it "listElement" but in reality it's a set that may contain one or more elements.

Comment: @Tomalak, well...yeah, I guess. Edited to indicate that there might be more than one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var span_required = $('li span.required');
var li_required = [];
$.each(span_required, function(index, item){
      li_required[index] = $(item).parents('li').get(0);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/rX2jA/

Answer (score 0):

```
var $required_items = $('li:has(span.required)');

var $required_items = $('li').has('span.required');
```

The latter one is probably faster: [jsperf test](http://jsperf.com/jquery-has-vs-has).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li:has(span.required)')
```

http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
$("li").filter(function() {
    return $(this).find("span.required").length > 0
})
```

Or [has](http://api.jquery.com/has/)

```
$("li").has("span.required")
```

**[Examples on jsFiddle](http://%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert%28%22filter%20found%22%29;)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
   alert( $('span.required').parents("li").length);
})();
```